# Totally stumped: array won't return value

Tags: php, csv, multidimensional-array

I'm by no means a pro concerning PHP, but usually I find my mistakes within a reasonable amount of time.
But this time I'm totally stumped.

I'm trying to read a .csv file and import it into a DB.
The file is being put into an array correctly, with the first row values taken as keys for the following row values. This can be seen with a print_r.

Now when iterating through the array with a foreach loop, the values are written into the DB. The first value in each row is the date and it's being ignored or probably rather shown as being empty which it isn't. The echo at the end gives no output.

I tried renaming the key, but that didn't help.

Can't seem to find the error....

CSV-Data:

```
Datum;Name;Platz;Runde;Spielform;CR/Slope;CR;Slope;Par;Brutto;Score;Kategorie;Power
02.09.2020;Extra Day Score;Nordkirchen, G&LC;1;Stableford;70,9/126;70,9;126;71;37;70;1;100
```

PHP-Code: (https://www.teamstolpe.de/test.php)

```
$tmpName = "test.csv";
    
$rows = array_map(function($v){return str_getcsv($v, ";");}, file($tmpName));
$header = array_shift($rows);
$csv    = [];
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}

echo "<b>print_r(csv) here:</b><br>";
print_r($csv);
echo "<br>--------<br>";
echo "<b>var_export(csv) here:</b><br>";
var_export($csv);
echo "<br>--------<br>";
echo "<b>print_r(csv[0]) here:</b><br>";
print_r($csv[0]);
echo "<br>--------<br>";
echo "<b>echo csv[0]['Datum'] here:</b> ".$csv[0]['Datum']."<br>-------------<br>";
    
foreach ($csv as $c) {
    
    echo "<b>print_r(c) here:</b><br>";
    print_r($c);
    echo "<br>--------<br>";
    echo "<b>echo c['Datum'] here:</b> ".$c['Datum']."<br>-------------<br>";
    echo "<b>echo csv[0]['Datum'] here:</b> ".$csv[0]['Datum']."<br>-------------<br>";

}
```

print_r ($csv):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Datum] => 02.09.2020
            [Name] => Extra Day Score
            [Platz] => Nordkirchen, G&LC
            [Runde] => 1
            [Spielform] => Stableford
            [CR/Slope] => 70,9/126
            [CR] => 70,9
            [Slope] => 126
            [Par] => 71
            [Brutto] => 37
            [Score] => 70
            [Kategorie] => 1
            [Power] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Datum] => 27.08.2020
            [Name] => EDS
            [Platz] => Münster-Tinnen, GC
            [Runde] => 1
            [Spielform] => Stableford
            [CR/Slope] => 71,6/126
            [CR] => 71,6
            [Slope] => 126
            [Par] => 72
            [Brutto] => 36
            [Score] => 72
            [Kategorie] => 1
            [Power] => 
        )
[...] 47 more rows like it
```

print_r($csv[0]) (print_r($c) within the foreach loop gives the same output):

```
Array
(
    [Datum] => 02.09.2020
    [Name] => Extra Day Score
    [Platz] => Nordkirchen, G&LC
    [Runde] => 1
    [Spielform] => Stableford
    [CR/Slope] => 70,9/126
    [CR] => 70,9
    [Slope] => 126
    [Par] => 71
    [Brutto] => 37
    [Score] => 70
    [Kategorie] => 1
    [Power] => 
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. I can see that you're trying to reformat the date (you might want to use [date_create_from_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead of manually parsing the date), but you never do anything with the result? You only echo the original value. Nor do I see any code for inserting anything? Please show us some proper examples of the original value, what you expect to get and what you currently get.

Comment: I left out the rest of the code as it's not relevant to the problem at hand. The echo $c['Datum'] should show '02.09.2019' but shows nothing instead. And the $date would also be empty instead of being a timestamp integer.

Comment: Since your `print_r()` outputs `[Datum] => 02.09.2020`, I don't see it as possible with the posted code. Do you overwrite/set `$c['Datum']` in any of the code you've removed?

Comment: If you get `$date` as empty, my guess is that your manual parsing of the date fails. As mentioned in the first comment, use `date_create_from_format()` instead, which will return a [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object. Then just call `->getTimestamp()` on the object to get the timestamp.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: thanks for the heads up with the PHP8 issue, I'll work on that.

Comment: I amended the question with the other print_r outputs. Those are all fine, regardless whether I call them in or before the foreach loop. Any echo of a value with the ['Datum'] key gives an empty output. As with the print_r outputs it doesn't matter whether they're called in the loop with echo $c['Datum'] or before with echo $csv[0]['Datum'], both is an empty output.

Comment: It's better to share `var_export` than `print_r` (I know others mentioned `print_r` specifically, I just wanted to give you advice for the future), because the contents of `var_export` can be directly copied to an editor to recreate the variable. It makes for easier testing.

Comment: I added the var_export to the code, as well as a link to a sample page with the outputs.

Comment: On that page I see `echo csv[0]['Datum'] here: 02.09.2020` being printed.

Comment: Indeed it is....although I don't know what I did to make it that way. BUT: on the live page it still is not working and more funny is when I tried to NULL the 'Datum' value in the array the var_export now shows two 'Datum' values: the original value up top and another one at the bottom with NULL `array (
  'Datum' => '02.09.2020',
  'Name' => 'Extra Day Score',
  [...]
  'Power' => 'NULL',
  'Datum' => NULL,
)` So I surmise there is nothing wrong with the code but rather with the csv file....

Comment: Most likely character encoding in the word then. If you `var_dump` the keys, you should be able to notice a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was not in the PHP code after all...

When accessing the $c['Datum'] value the code counldn't find anything because somehow 'Datum' is not the same as 'Datum'.

When I grab the key from the original array and assign the converted timestamp to it like this:

```
$dateField = $rows[0][0];
$date = date_create_from_format("d.m.Y", $c[$dateField]);
$c[$dateField] = $date->getTimestamp();
```

it's suddenly working.
Maybe something with the character encoding...very strange indeed.

Thanks for the valuable tips regarding the timestamp transformation and var_export.
Cheers!